# Bootstrap SelectPicker - Multiple doesn't give array, just string

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select in HTML using SelectPicker to set multiple values, like this:

```
<select name="filtro_tipo[]" id="filtro_tipo[]" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>1" onchange="changeTipo()">
 <option value="J" selected>Jurídico</option>
 <option value="F" selected>Físico</option>
</select>
```

In a previous application that works fine, but now when I post that data I get this:

```
[filtro_tipo] => Array
        (
            [0] => J,F
        )
```

Two values in same position separated by ','. That is wrong, I would like two array position, which one with a value.

Someone wonder why it is happening? As I said, in another application I get the correct array...

Comment: What is in the `changeTipo()` Javascript function?

Comment: in id why you declare this as a array and data-selected-text-format="count>1" is this right there a symbol ">" if it is ok then please show more code for solution

Comment: @priya786 Seems like he is using bootstrap-select. The docs for it can be found at: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: DavidG, calls some information to change some labels, not relevant in this select and in the result array...